# ThreeJS creating a sun

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, webgl

I am trying to create a solar system in WebGL.
However i have no idea to set up the lighting. 
I want to put a light in my sun and have it cast light 360 degrees. My planets should cast and receive shadows. To achieve that , my light would need to cast shadows 360 degrees.
Is it possible to do something like that? If so, how? Which type of light should i use?

My sun has a meshBasicMaterial, my planets have a meshShaderMaterial. Could anyone be so kind to provide me some example code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add a `THREE.PointLight` for the sun - it will cast light to all directions.

The shadows are trickier as the point light in Three.js does not support shadow casting. You have a few less than ideal options:

- Use 6 shadow-only spot or directional lights with the shadow cameras arranged to point to each world axes (i.e. into a cube). This is going to be rather expensive.
- Use one (or more) shadow casting light that is pointed to the area of greatest interest, e.g. where the user is currently looking.
- Implement omni-directional shadow mapping yourself (e.g. dual paraboloid shadows only need two shadow maps instead of 6).
- Omit shadows. There's not really many surfaces in space that could receive shadows, so do you really need them?

Note that with a custom `ShaderMaterial` on a shadow-receiving object, you need to implement shadows yourself in the shader (or include three.js' shadowing code chunks).

Comment: Good answer, I'm gonna go with a light that always points to the area where the user is looking, as i am a web developer and not a 3D programmer and i do not know how to write my own shaders. Adding a shadow is not important for now but it makes things more realistic (f. ex the moon dropping a shadow on the earth etc.).

Comment: Note that the THREE.PointLight can now cast shadows.
https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/lights/PointLight

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you would need to use an omnidirectional light.

Comment: A pointlight is a 360 degrees light. However it does not support shadowcasting.